# Integrals of $q$-series

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, definite-integrals, infinite-product, pochhammer-symbol

Let $|q|<1$  and define the [$q$-shifted factorials](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/q-PochhammerSymbol.html) as $$(a;q)_{n} := \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(1-a q^{i} \right) ,$$ with the limiting cases $$\left(a;q \right)_{0} = 1 $$ and $$\left( a;q \right)_{\infty} = \prod_{i=0}^{\infty} \left(1-a q^{i} \right) .$$

In the following [article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022314X16302621) by M. E. Bachraoui, the following identities are stated in equations $(12)$ and $(13)$ for $|q|<1$ :

$$ \int_{- \frac{1}{2} \ln(q) }^{ \frac{1}{2} \ln(q) } \ln \left( q e^{\pm 2x} ; q^{2} \right)_{\infty} dx = \frac{\zeta(2)}{2}. $$

When I saw these identities, it was the first time I encountered a definite integral of a $q$-series or $q$-Pochhammer symbol. I haven't seen any since.

> **Question**: what other definite integrals involving $q$-series have been evaluated in the past? Pointers to relevant references from the literature are much appreciated.

Comment: I suppose here are some interesting examples as well, but I'm particularly interested in $q$-series integrals whose evaluation involves zeta values: http://oeis.org/A258232/a258232_2.pdf